# Debian network problems in Virtualbox

Tags: windows-7, linux, networking, virtualbox, debian

I have virtualbox 4.3.20 (win 7 x64) and debian 7.7 stable wheezy  installed on my computer. My network settings for VB are: Attached to bridged adapter, promiscous mode deny My problems is that networking in problematic. When I start downloading (apt-get or else) it halts. Sometimes it continues and sometimes connection fails.

It works for a some seconds and then problems start. Network is idle for 5-20 sec and then it continues.

Comment: What model network card does your computer have? Some have better virtualization support than others.  What model network card are you showing to the virtual machine? Do you have VirtualBox Guest Additions installed in the VM?

Comment: I will need to try with guest addons then. I used it in a GUI environment for full screen. Since I used this as a console. I wasn't aware that I need Guest Addons.

Comment: Can you also answer the other two questions about the network adapter types (the kind on the computer and the virtualized kind on the VM)?

Comment: Intel Advanced-N 6200 AGN, on the virtualized is Bridged Adapter Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6200 AGN. I tried to install new Guest addition but could mount the drive. The drive was mounted in VB but not in Debian.  I didn't have such problems using Linux Mint (Ubuntu). I tried VMWare player and it works well with Debian.

Comment: OK, the Intel 6200 works pretty well with VirtualBox in my experience.  How about how it shows itself to the VM? Click "Advanced" on the VM's "Network" settings and look for "Adapter Type".

Comment: not promiscouus since the wireless is used.

Comment: You are still missing the "Adapter Type". See http://i.imgur.com/HJ462LP.png

Comment: I have Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (82540OEM) selected. This my configuration: http://i.imgur.com/NYa62qp.png. I have 4.1.18_Debian installed in Debian 7.7 stable. And I cannot installe newer version. Image is added to options via Install guest additions but I cannot see anything in /media mounted.

Comment: Part of your problem could be that the host VBox version 4.3.20 doesn't match the guest additions version 4.1.18.  To get the image to mount, try running `sudo mount -t iso9660 -o defaults /dev/sr0 /media/cdrom`.

Comment: I installed the new guest addition and tested again. Problem still persist. :/ I will use VMPlayer

Comment: Try switching to the "virtio" network driver. (You will need to reboot the VM.)

Comment: Now I use 2 cards, 1st as NAT and second as bridged. I have Internet now but occasionally network disconnect, I believe I can solve that problem when I download sth by using download manager. BTW I am using Debian Jessy RC2 now.